# Формирование траектории по поверхности полигональной модели

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сейчас разрабатываю прогу для обработки деталей по полигональным моделям в Unity. И нужно как-то формировать траекторию по поверхности полигональной модели. Например найти точки пересечения с плоскостью (должна получиться кривая линия в итоге).

Есть какие-то простые инструменты, чтобы легко искать точки пересечения коллайдеров?

Пока первое что приходит в голову:

1. Это формировать рейкасты с определённым шагом по плосоксти (это кажется не очень элегантным решением.
2. Использовать векторную алгебру и искать пересечение плоскости с плоскостью каждого полигона (это задача выглядит очень сложной, так что склонняюсь к ней в последнюю очередь)

Comment: Вы бы хоть пример привели, что в вашем понятии "траектория по модели"? По одной сетке можно много траекторий провести.

Comment: Эм... Боюсь в варианте 1. уже заключается вариант 2. и алгебру никто не перехитрил.